# how to restrict heartbeat activity messages per roles?? i am using drupal 7

Tags: rules, users, heartbeat

Message display access
Defines to whom the message is meant for and who is entitled to see the message.
Limit this message with roles
anonymous user
authenticated user
administrator
moderator
Guest
Select the roles to filter activity. Leaving empty means the messages will always be shown.